# What's the preferred way to implement a hook or callback in Python?

Tags: python, callback, hook, factory

I'd like to provide the capability for users of one of my modules to extend its capabilities by providing an interface to call a user's function. For example, I want to give users the capability to be notified when an instance of a class is created and given the opportunity to modify the instance before it is used.

The way I've implemented it is to declare a module-level factory function that does the instantiation:

```
# in mymodule.py
def factory(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then when I need an instance of a class in mymodule, I do `factory(cls, arg1, arg2)` rather than `cls(arg1, arg2)`.

To extend it, a programmer would write in another module a function like this:

```
def myFactory(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = myFactory.chain(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    # do something with the instance here if desired
    return instance
```

Installation of the above callback looks like this:

```
myFactory.chain, mymodule.factory = mymodule.factory, myFactory
```

This seems straightforward enough to me, but I was wondering if you, as a Python programmer, would expect a function to register a callback rather than doing it with an assignment, or if there were other methods you would expect. Does my solution seem workable, idiomatic, and clear to you?

I am looking to keep it as simple as possible; I don't think most applications will actually need to chain more than one user callback, for example (though unlimited chaining comes "for free" with the above pattern). I doubt they will need to remove callbacks or specify priorities or order.  Modules like [python-callbacks](http://python-callbacks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/callbacks.html) or [PyDispatcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDispatcher/2.0.1) seem to me like overkill, especially the latter, but if there are compelling benefits to a programmer working with my module, I'm open to them.

Comment: What's wrong with using a simple subclass to extend a class?  Why all this confusion call-back business?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Combining Aaron's idea of using a decorator and Ignacio's idea of a class that maintains a list of attached callbacks, plus a concept borrowed from C#, I came up with this:

```
class delegate(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.callbacks = []
        self.basefunc = func

    def __iadd__(self, func):
        if callable(func):
            self.__isub__(func)
            self.callbacks.append(func)
        return self

    def callback(self, func):
        if callable(func):
            self.__isub__(func)
            self.callbacks.append(func)
        return func

    def __isub__(self, func):
        try:
            self.callbacks.remove(func)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.basefunc(*args, **kwargs)
        for func in self.callbacks:
            newresult = func(result)
            result = result if newresult is None else newresult
        return result
```

Decorating a function with `@delegate` allows other functions to be "attached" to it.

```
@delegate
def intfactory(num):
    return int(num)
```

Functions can be added to the delegate with `+=` (and removed with `-=`). You can also decorate with `funcname.callback` to add a callback function.

```
@intfactory.callback
def notify(num):
    print "notify:", num

def increment(num):
    return num+1

intfactory += increment
intfactory += lambda num: num * 2

print intfactory(3)   # outputs 8
```

Does this feel Pythonic?

Comment: Feels more like a delegate, which isn't exactly Pythonic *per se*, but I see no problem in doing it this way.

Comment: Yeah, when I was thinking about this some more, I thought it was a lot like C# delegates. Perhaps I should actually name the class "delegate."

Comment: Thinking about it even more, I don't really need the metaclass. I originally wanted to be able to get the functionality without instantiating the class, but the way I've got it written now, it would probably be more understandable with instantiation. Some more work is probably warranted.

Comment: I've made the aforementioned changes.

Answer (score 14):

Taking [aaronsterling's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309607/whats-the-preferred-way-to-implement-a-hook-or-callback-in-python/4309633#4309633) a bit further:

```
class C(object):
  _oncreate = []

  def __new__(cls):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), cls._oncreate, super(C, cls).__new__(cls))

  @classmethod
  def oncreate(cls, func):
    cls._oncreate.append(func)

c = C()
print hasattr(c, 'spew')

@C.oncreate
def spew(obj):
  obj.spew = 42
  return obj

c = C()
print c.spew
```

Comment: That is a really elegant approach for the specific use case of instantiating a class.

Answer (score 6):

I might use a decorator so that the user could just write.

```
@new_factory
def myFactory(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = myFactory.chain(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    # do something with the instance here if desired
    return instance
```

Then in your module,

```
import sys

def new_factory(f):
    mod = sys.modules[__name__]
    f.chain = mod.factory
    mod.factory = f
    return f
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I could add a wrapper that does the `chain` call, so that the user doesn't have to write that part. It also nicely supports the use case where the user wants to add the callback function at some time other than when the function is defined.