# Difference between decorator classes and decorator functions

Tags: python, syntax, decorator

I guess that's how they are called, but I will give examples just in case.

Decorator class:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'something'
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Decorator function:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'something'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Is using one or the other just a matter of taste? Is there any practical difference?

Comment: There is a difference. The difference is exactly the same when you'd want to use a regular function versus a regular class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can write a function to implement your decorator you should prefer it. But not all decorators can easily be written as a function - for example when you want to store some internal state.

```
class counted(object):
    """ counts how often a function is called """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.counter = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)


@counted
def something():
    pass

something()
print something.counter
```

I've seen people (including myself) go through ridiculous efforts to write decorators only with functions. I still have no idea why, the overhead of a class is usually totally negligible.

Comment: Of course this *can* be written as a function.  But in Python you usually prefer a class over a closure to hide state.

Comment: I actually like the Python (3.x) version of this (using braces \*sob\* since comments eat line breaks): `def counted(f) { x = 0; def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) { nonlocal x; x += 1; f(*args, **kwargs) } return wrapper }`. The 2.x version is plain ugly though (hacking around the lack of `nonlocal` with using a singleton list and using it's single item).

Comment: You could also use an attribute of the wrapper function to hold the counter.

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, `nonlocal` is very useful, but in Py2 you can also write `def wrapped( ... ): wrapped.counter +=1; ... ` in the decorator (functions are mutable too). I can't really think of a good example for my answer; just imagine something more complicated ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is generally just a matter of taste. Most Python programs use duck typing and don't really care whether the thing they're calling is a function or an instance of some other type, so long as it is callable. And anything with a `__call__()` method is callable.

There are a few advantages to using function-style decorators:

- Much cleaner when your decorator doesn't return a wrapper function (i.e., it returns the original function after doing something to it, such as setting an attribute).
- No need to explicitly save the reference to the original function, as this is done by the closure.
- Most of the tools that help you make decorators, such as `functools.wraps()` or Michele Simionato's signature-preserving `decorator` module, work with function-style decorators.
- There may be some programs out there somewhere which don't use duck typing, but actually expect a function type, so returning a function to replace a function is theoretically "safer."

For these reasons, I use function-style decorators most of the time. As a counterexample, however, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309607/whats-the-preferred-way-to-implement-a-hook-or-callback-in-python/4321509#4321509) is a recent instance in which the class-style decorator was more natural for me.

Comment: `functools.wraps()` may be intended to work with function-style decorators, but `functools.update_wrapper(self, wrapped)` in the `__init__` of a class-style decorator works perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed class decorator implementation has a slight difference with the function implementation : it will fail on methods

```
class Decorator(object):
def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print('something')
    self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class A:
    @Decorator
    def mymethod(self):
        print("method")

A().mymethod()
```

will raise `TypeError: mymethod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

To add support of methods, you need to implement the `__get__`

```
import types
class Decorator2(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('something')
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, instance)

class B:

    @Decorator2
    def mymethod(self):
        print("method")

B().mymethod()
```

will output

class B:...

```
something
method
```

The reason it works is that when you access `B().mymethod`, the `__get__` is called first and supplies the bound method. Then `__call__` is called

To conclude, provided you define the `__get__`, class and function implementation can be used the same way. See python cookbook recipe 9.9 for more information.

Comment: This issue never seems to be addressed.  Apparently it's in the Python cookbook, but none of "python tutorial" pages that talk about decorators as classes ever consider its use with methods.  Seems like an obvious pitfall with what ends up being a simple solution.  Thanks for this!  Wish I could give you more than 1 upvote!