# Python decorator best practice, using a class vs a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, syntactic-sugar

As I've understood it there are two ways to do a Python decorator, to either use the `__call__` of a class or to define and call a function as the decorator. What's the advantages/disadvantages of these methods? Is there one preferred method?

Example 1

```
class dec1(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self):
        print "Decorating", self.f.__name__
        self.f()

@dec1
def func1():
    print "inside func1()"

func1()

# Decorating func1
# inside func1()
```

Example 2

```
def dec2(f):
    def new_f():
        print "Decorating", f.__name__
        f()
    return new_f

@dec2
def func2():
    print "inside func2()"

func2()

# Decorating func2
# inside func2()
```

Comment: One important thing: your actual wrapper functions call the original `f` function but do not return its returned value to the callee: this most likely would lead to an incorrect behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between decorator classes and decorator functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650333/difference-between-decorator-classes-and-decorator-functions)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It is rather subjective to say whether there are "advantages" to each method.

However, a good understanding of what goes under the hood would make it natural
for one to pick the best choice for each occasion.

A decorator (talking about function decorators), is simply a callable object that takes a function as its input parameter. Python has its rather interesting design that allows
one to create other kinds of callable objects, besides functions - and one can put that to use
to create more maintainable or shorter code on occasion.

Decorators were added back in Python 2.3 as a "syntactic shortcut" for

```
def a(x):
   ...

a = my_decorator(a)
```

Besides that, we usually call decorators some "callables" that would rather be "decorator factories" - when we use this kind:

```
@my_decorator(param1, param2)
def my_func(...):
   ...
```

the call is made to "my_decorator" with param1 and param2 - it then returns an object that will be called again, this time having "my_func" as a parameter. So, in this case, technically the "decorator" is whatever is returned by the "my_decorator", making it a
"decorator factory".

Now, either decorators or "decorator factories" as described usually have to keep some internal state. In the first case, the only thing it does keep is a reference to the original function (the variable called `f` in your examples). A "decorator factory" may want to register extra state variables ("param1" and "param2" in the example above).

This extra state, in the case of decorators written as functions is kept in variables within the enclosing functions, and accessed as "nonlocal" variables by the actual wrapper function. If one writes a proper class, they can be kept as instance variables in the decorator function (which will be seen as a "callable object", not a "function") - and access to them is more explicit and more readable.

So, for most cases it is a matter of readability whether you will prefer one approach or the other:
for short, simple decorators, the functional approach is often more readable than one written as a class - while sometimes a more elaborate one - especially one "decorator factory" will take full advantage of the "flat is better than nested" advice fore Python coding.

Consider:

```
def my_dec_factory(param1, param2):
   ...
   ...
   def real_decorator(func):
       ...
       def wraper_func(*args, **kwargs):
           ...
           #use param1
           result = func(*args, **kwargs)
           #use param2
           return result
       return wraper_func
   return real_decorator
```

against this "hybrid" solution:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
    """Decorator example mixing class and function definitions."""
    def __init__(self, func, param1, param2):
        self.func = func
        self.param1, self.param2 = param1, param2

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        #use self.param1
        result = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        #use self.param2
        return result

def my_dec_factory(param1, param2):
    def decorator(func):
         return MyDecorator(func, param1, param2)
    return decorator
```

**update**: Missing "pure class" forms of decorators

Now, note the "hybrid" method takes the "best of both Worlds" trying to keep the shortest and more readable code. A full "decorator factory" defined exclusively with classes would either need two classes, or a "mode" attribute to know if it was called to register the decorated function or to actually call the final function:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
   """Decorator example defined entirely as class."""
   def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        ...
        self.mode = "decorating"

   def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.mode == "decorating":
             self.func = args[0]
             self.mode = "calling"
             return self
        # code to run prior to function call
        result = self.func(*args, **kw)
        # code to run after function call
        return result

@MyDecorator(p1, ...)
def myfunc():
    ...
```

And finally a pure, "white colar" decorator defined with two classes - maybe keeping things more separated, but increasing the redundancy to a point one can't say it is more maintainable:

```
class Stage2Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func, p1, p2, ...):
         self.func = func
         self.p1 = p1
         ...
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
         # code to run prior to function call
         ...
         result = self.func(*args, **kw)
         # code to run after function call
         ...
         return result

class Stage1Decorator(object):
   """Decorator example defined as two classes.
   
   No "hacks" on the object model, most bureacratic.
   """
   def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        ...
        self.mode = "decorating"

   def __call__(self, func):
       return Stage2Decorator(func, self.p1, self.p2, ...)


@Stage1Decorator(p1, p2, ...)
def myfunc():
    ...
```

## 2018 update

I wrote the text above a couple years ago. I came up recently with a pattern I prefer due to creating code that is "flatter".

The basic idea is to use a function, but return a `partial` object of itself if it is called with parameters before being used as a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def decorator(func=None, parameter1=None, parameter2=None, ...):

   if not func:
        # The only drawback is that for functions there is no thing
        # like "self" - we have to rely on the decorator 
        # function name on the module namespace
        return partial(decorator, parameter1=parameter1, parameter2=parameter2)
   @wraps(func)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Decorator code-  parameter1, etc... can be used 
        # freely here
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

And that is it - decorators written using this pattern can decorate
a function right away without being "called" first:

```
@decorator
def my_func():
    pass
```

Or customized with parameters:

```
@decorator(parameter1="example.com", ...):
def my_func():
    pass
```

**2019** - With Python 3.8 and positional only parameters this last pattern will become even better, as the `func` argument can be declared as positional only, and require the parameters to be named;

```
def decorator(func=None, /, *, parameter1=None, parameter2=None, ...):
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. To avoid the "self.mode" you can also return a function inside the __call__. e.g. def __call__(self, func): def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): return func(*args,**kwargs) return wrapper

Comment: All the approaches that use a `class` callable object have the same problem, they can't make use of `wraps`. Have you considered adding a `__str__(self)` that returns, something like `"<function %s at 0x%x>" % (self.func.__name__, hash(self))`? It is also possible to copy `__name__` and `__doc__` from wrapee to the instance (e.g., `MyDecorator` or `Stage2Decorator`), but this doesn't really help in IPython.

Comment: sorry - this post does not have the purpose of "disguising a decorated function so it is not distinguishable from the original one". Of course anyone can creat a `__repr__` (`__str__` would be mostly useless) method with information on what is being wrapped.
Still you have a point - `functools.wraps`  does more than simply copying over the wrapped function  `__name__`, and there is no ready-made equivalent to that functionality that can be used with a class based approach.

Comment: Nice @jsbueno. Thanks for this. Question though: When using a function for a deco factory you can look at the params and change the signature (`@wraps`) according to them. How do you do that if you use a class for this purpose? You see the problem? You can `@wraps` the `__call__`, but only within the scope of the class, which hasn't seen the parameter values yet.

Comment: very nice answer, I shall also say that instead of using `/` as offered in the 2019 edit, one can use `*` which is exactly the contrary: it specifies that the argument are keyword only.

Comment: yes - thanks - "*" is definitely  the correct thing here (editing now)

Comment: The  last 2019 update, it seems if you add this it's calling the decorated function directly without it even being called manually.

Comment: the "2019 update" goes on top of the  "2018 update" - the `if not func: ` block will handle that.

Answer (score 12):

I mostly agree with jsbueno: there's no one right way. It depends on the situation. But I think def is probably better in most cases, because if you go with class, most of the "real" work is going to be done in `__call__` anyway. Also, callables that are not functions are pretty rare (with the notable exception of instantiating a class), and people generally do not expect that. Also, local variables are usually easier for people to keep track of vs. instance variables, simply because they have more limited scope, although in this case, the instance variables are probably only used in `__call__` (with `__init__` simply copying them from arguments).

I have to disagree with his hybrid approach though. It's an interesting design, but I think it's probably going to confuse the crap out of you or someone else who looks at it a few months later.

Tangent: Regardless of whether you go with class or function, you should use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which itself is meant to be used as a decorator (we must go deeper!) like so:

```
import functools

def require_authorization(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorated(user, *args, **kwargs):
        if not is_authorized(user):
            raise UserIsNotAuthorized
        return f(user, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@require_authorization
def check_email(user, etc):
    # etc.
```

This makes `decorated` look like `check_email` e.g. by changing it's `func_name` attribute.

Anyway, this is usually what I do and what I see other people around me doing, unless I want a decorator factory. In that case, I just add another level of def:

```
def require_authorization(action):
    def decorate(f):
        @functools.wraps(f):
        def decorated(user, *args, **kwargs):
            if not is_allowed_to(user, action):
                raise UserIsNotAuthorized(action, user)
            return f(user, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorate
```

By the way, I would also be on guard against excessive use of decorators, because they can make it really hard to follow stack traces.

One approach for managing hideous stack traces is to have a policy of not substantially changing the behavior of the decoratee. E.g.

```
def log_call(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug('call being made: %s(*%r, **%r)',
                      f.func_name, args, kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

A more extreme approach for keeping your stack traces sane is for the decorator to return the decoratee unmodified, like so:

```
import threading

DEPRECATED_LOCK = threading.Lock()
DEPRECATED = set()

def deprecated(f):
    with DEPRECATED_LOCK:
        DEPRECATED.add(f)
    return f

@deprecated
def old_hack():
    # etc.
```

This is useful if the function is called within a framework that knows about the `deprecated` decorator. E.g.

```
class MyLamerFramework(object):
    def register_handler(self, maybe_deprecated):
        if not self.allow_deprecated and is_deprecated(f):
            raise ValueError(
                'Attempted to register deprecated function %s as a handler.'
                % f.func_name)
        self._handlers.add(maybe_deprecated)
```

Comment: What I call "hybrid approach" is just making the `__call__` method to act like a decorator itself - getting the to-be-decorated function as a parameter. COuld you give an example of a class decorator that would not do so?  (For such, the `__call__` would have to feed the object still in another object, probably of another class, tightly coupled with the first - or - hold a state to "know" if it had already being bound to a function or not.  - both things I find rather more confusing than having `__call__` wrap the decorated function itself.

Answer (score 7):

I will dare to offer a different approach to the problem almost seven years after the question was originally made. This version is not described in any of the previous (very nice!) answers.

The biggest differences between using classes and functions as decorators are already very well described here. For the sake of completeness I'll go briefly  through this again, but to be more practical, I'm going to use a concrete example.

Let's say you want to write a decorator to cache the result of "pure" functions (those free of side effects, so the return value is deterministic, given the arguments) in some cache service.

Here are two equivalent and very simple decorators for doing this, in both flavors (functional and object oriented):

```
import json
import your_cache_service as cache

def cache_func(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = json.dumps([f.__name__, args, kwargs])
        cached_value = cache.get(key)
        if cached_value is not None:
            print('cache HIT')
            return cached_value
        print('cache MISS')
        value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        cache.set(key, value)
        return value
    return wrapper

class CacheClass(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.orig_func = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key = json.dumps([self.orig_func.__name__, args, kwargs])
        cached_value = cache.get(key)
        if cached_value is not None:
            print('cache HIT')
            return cached_value
        print('cache MISS')
        value = self.orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        cache.set(key, value)
        return value
```

I guess this is fairly easy to understand. It's just a silly example! I'm skipping all error handling and edge cases for simplicity. You should not ctrl+c/ctrl+v code from StackOverflow anyways, right? ;)

As one can notice, both versions are essentially the same. The object oriented version is a bit longer and more verbose than the functional one, because we have to define methods and use the variable `self`, but I would argue it is slightly more readable. This factor becomes really important for more complex decorators. We'll see that in a moment.

The decorators above are used like this:

```
@cache_func
def test_one(a, b=0, c=1):
    return (a + b)*c

# Behind the scenes:
#     test_one = cache_func(test_one)

print(test_one(3, 4, 6))
print(test_one(3, 4, 6))

# Prints:
#     cache MISS
#     42
#     cache HIT
#     42

@CacheClass
def test_two(x, y=0, z=1):
    return (x + y)*z

# Behind the scenes:
#     test_two = CacheClass(test_two)

print(test_two(1, 1, 569))
print(test_two(1, 1, 569))

# Prints:
#     cache MISS
#     1138
#     cache HIT
#     1138
```

But let's say now that your cache service supports setting the TTL for each cache entry. You would need to defined that on decoration time. How to do it?

The traditional functional approach would be to add a new wrapper layer that returns a configured decorator (there are nicer suggestions in the other answers to this question):

```
import json
import your_cache_service as cache

def cache_func_with_options(ttl=None):
    def configured_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            key = json.dumps([f.__name__, args, kwargs])
            cached_value = cache.get(key)
            if cached_value is not None:
                print('cache HIT')
                return cached_value
            print('cache MISS')
            value = f(*args, **kwargs)
            cache.set(key, value, ttl=ttl)
            return value
        return wrapper
    return configured_decorator
```

It is used like this:

```
from time import sleep

@cache_func_with_options(ttl=100)
def test_three(a, b=0, c=1):
    return hex((a + b)*c)

# Behind the scenes:
#     test_three = cache_func_with_options(ttl=100)(test_three)

print(test_three(8731))
print(test_three(8731))
sleep(0.2)
print(test_three(8731))

# Prints:
#     cache MISS
#     0x221b
#     cache HIT
#     0x221b
#     cache MISS
#     0x221b
```

This one is still okay, but I have to admit that, even being an experienced developer, sometimes I see myself taking a good amount of time to understand more complex decorators that follow this pattern. The tricky part here is that is really not possible to "un-nest" the functions, as the inner functions need the variables defined in the scope of the outer ones.

Can the object oriented version help? I think so, but if you follow the previous structure for the class-based one, it would end up with the same nested structure as the functional one or, even worse, using flags to hold the state of what the decorator is doing (not nice).

So, instead of receiving the function to be decorated in the `__init__` method and handling the wrapping and decorator parameters in the `__call__` method (or using multiple classes/functions to do so, which is too complex to my taste), my suggestion is to handle the decorator parameters in the `__init__` method, receive the function in the `__call__` method and finally handle the wrapping in an additional method that is returned by the end of the `__call__`.

It looks like this:

```
import json
import your_cache_service as cache

class CacheClassWithOptions(object):
    def __init__(self, ttl=None):
        self.ttl = ttl

    def __call__(self, f):
        self.orig_func = f
        return self.wrapper

    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key = json.dumps([self.orig_func.__name__, args, kwargs])
        cached_value = cache.get(key)
        if cached_value is not None:
            print('cache HIT')
            return cached_value
        print('cache MISS')
        value = self.orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        cache.set(key, value, ttl=self.ttl)
        return value
```

The usage is as expected:

```
from time import sleep

@CacheClassWithOptions(ttl=100)
def test_four(x, y=0, z=1):
    return (x + y)*z

# Behind the scenes:
#     test_four = CacheClassWithOptions(ttl=100)(test_four)

print(test_four(21, 42, 27))
print(test_four(21, 42, 27))
sleep(0.2)
print(test_four(21, 42, 27))

# Prints:
#     cache MISS
#     1701
#     cache HIT
#     1701
#     cache MISS
#     1701
```

As anything is perfect, there are two small drawbacks with this last approach:

1. It's not possible to decorate using `@CacheClassWithOptions` directly. We have to use parenthesis `@CacheClassWithOptions()`, even if we don't want to pass any parameter. This is because we need to create the instance first, before trying to decorate, so the `__call__` method will receive the function to be decorated, not in the `__init__`. It is possible to work around this limitation, but it's very hacky. Better to simply accept that those parenthesis are needed.
2. There's no obvious place to apply the `functools.wraps` decorator on the returned wrapped function, what would be a no-brainer in the functional version. It can easily be done, though, by creating an intermediary function inside `__call__` before returning. It just doesn't look that nice and it's better to leave that out if you don't need the nice things that `functools.wraps` does.

Comment: In your final example, you can accomplish what `functools.wraps` does by calling `update_wrapper(self.wrapper.__func__, f)` right before `return self.wrapper`.

Comment: Note: your solution (as shown in `CacheClassWithOptions`) won't work for decorating instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different decorator implementations. One of these uses a class as a decorator and the other uses a function as a decorator. You must choose the preferred implementation for your needs.

For example, if your decorator does a lot of work then you can use class as a decorator, like this:

```
import logging
import time
import pymongo
import hashlib
import random

DEBUG_MODE = True

class logger(object):

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                if DEBUG_MODE:
                        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                        return args[0]

        def __init__(self, foo):
                self.foo = foo
                logging.basicConfig(filename='exceptions.log', format='%(levelname)s %   (asctime)s: %(message)s')
                self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                def _log():
                        try:
                               t = time.time()
                               func_hash = self._make_hash(t)
                               col = self._make_db_connection()
                               log_record = {'func_name':self.foo.__name__, 'start_time':t, 'func_hash':func_hash}
                               col.insert(log_record)
                               res = self.foo(*args, **kwargs)
                               log_record = {'func_name':self.foo.__name__, 'exc_time':round(time.time() - t,4), 'end_time':time.time(),'func_hash':func_hash}
                               col.insert(log_record)
                               return res
                        except Exception as e:
                               self.log.error(e)
                return _log()

        def _make_db_connection(self):
                connection = pymongo.Connection()
                db = connection.logger
                collection = db.log
                return collection

        def _make_hash(self, t):
                m = hashlib.md5()
                m.update(str(t)+str(random.randrange(1,10)))
                return m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Yes, but I still wonder about advantages / disadvantages for the two ways of doing it and when to use what. Ok, class decorator can be a little bit more advanced I guess? Any disadvantages?

Comment: OK, decorator its a function or class which takes function or class on input. And now you can think of in which cases it is convenient to use function or when you want to use class.

Comment: This answer is conceptually wrong: this is not a "class decorator" - a "class decorator" decorates a class, and it is  not correleated with wether its implementation is a class or a function.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question, for me it didn't matter which one to use better, I decided to check which of the options has better performance.

My Class Decorator is without `__call__` to don't create the object every run.

It was important for me to add a global field some_data, to which in the case of a function decorator I referred through nonlocal.

- As a result: the option with **a class decorator is 15-20% faster.**

Tested on **python 3.11**

#### Result

- the class decorator way is `0.16s`
- the decorator way is `0.19s`

#### Class Decorator way

```py
from typing import Callable

class Handler:

    def handle(self, message):
        return 10 ** 12 / 123


class HandlerDecorator:

    def __init__(self, method: Callable):
        self.method = method
        self.some_data = 123

    def handle(self, message):
        i = 100 * 19 / self.some_data
        self.method(message)
        self.some_data = i


handler = Handler()
consumer = HandlerDecorator(handler.handle)
class_wrapped_method = consumer.handle
```

#### Decorator way

```py
from typing import Callable


def handler_wrapper(method: Callable) -> Callable:
    some_data = 123

    def wrapped_method(*args):
        nonlocal some_data
        i = 100 * 19 / some_data
        method(*args)
        some_data = i

    return wrapped_method


class DecoratedHandler:

    @handler_wrapper
    def handle(self, message):
        return 10 ** 12 / 123


decorated_handler = DecoratedHandler()
decorated_method = decorated_handler.handle
```

#### Test code

- Called class decorator with wrapped method: `class_wrapped_method('message')`
- Called decorated method of the class: `decorated_method('message')`

#### Full source code

```py
import timeit

setup_class_code = """
from typing import Callable

class Handler:

    def handle(self, message):
        return 10 ** 12 / 123


class HandlerDecorator:

    def __init__(self, method: Callable):
        self.method = method
        self.some_data = 123

    def handle(self, message):
        i = 100 * 19 / self.some_data
        self.method(message)
        self.some_data = i


handler = Handler()
consumer = HandlerDecorator(handler.handle)
class_wrapped_method = consumer.handle
"""

setup_decorated_code = """
from typing import Callable


def handler_wrapper(method: Callable) -> Callable:
    some_data = 123

    def wrapped_method(*args):
        nonlocal some_data
        i = 100 * 19 / some_data
        method(*args)
        some_data = i

    return wrapped_method


class DecoratedHandler:

    @handler_wrapper
    def handle(self, message):
        return 10 ** 12 / 123


decorated_handler = DecoratedHandler()
decorated_method = decorated_handler.handle
"""
test_class_code = "class_wrapped_method('message')"
test_decorate_code = "decorated_method('message')"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    timings = timeit.timeit(stmt=test_class_code, setup=setup_class_code)
    print(timings)
    timings = timeit.timeit(stmt=test_decorate_code, setup=setup_decorated_code)
    print(timings)
```