# Nesting functions decorated with same decorator returns error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-decorators

I'm starting to work with decorators, and I'm struggling with using the same class decorator in two nested functions. For instance, given the following decorator -implementation inspired in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086840/decorator-class-and-missing-required-positional-arguments)-

```
class PrintEvent():
    
    def __init__(self, fn=None):
        self.fn=fn
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        try:
            out=self.fn(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)
            print(f'Function {self.fn.__name__} executed succesfully.')
        except:
            out=None
            print(f'Function {self.fn.__name__} failed: {traceback.format_exc()}')

        return out
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        
        self.instance=instance
        return self
```

I'm trying to decorate the following,

```
@PrintEvent
def foo_function(number):
    return number * 2


class FooClass:
    
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var=var

    @PrintEvent
    def foo_method(self):
        output=foo_function(self.var)                
        return output
```

Decorator `PrintEvent` decorates both function `foo_function` and *FooClass* method `foo_method`. The output I'm getting at the moment when executing

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    test=FooClass(2)
    test.foo_method()
```

is the following,

```
Function foo_function failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xxxx...", line 11, in __call__
    out=self.fn(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'PrintEvent' object has no attribute 'instance'

Function foo_method executed succesfully.
```

Following the traceback, the reason is that the `PrintEvent.__get__` method is called when invoking `foo_method`, but not when calling `foo_function`. Therefore, attribute *instance* is not generated for the latter, and an error is raised.

If I understand correctly, I would be doing the following with this code:

`PrintEvent.__call__(FooClass.foo_method(PrintEvent.__call__(foo_function)))`

The question would be

1. Why does `PrintEvent.__get__` method is only invoked once, if `PrintEvent.__call__` is called twice?
2. How could one workaround this?
3. Finally, any comments or suggestions on the proposed structure will be very appreciated

Thanks a lot beforehand

Comment: Why would `PrintEvent.__get__` be invoked more than once? Maybe you're misunderstanding what object the descriptor is invoked against. Here's an existing question that may answer your question: [Understanding `__get__` and `__set__` and Python descriptors](/q/3798835/4518341). [Sorry, I posted the same comment already, but just noticed a typo.]

Comment: BTW, note that in the linked answer, `__get__` doesn't modify `self`. With your code, if you run `test.foo_method()`, then `FooClass.foo_method()` will behave as if it were `test.foo_method()`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will revisit the descriptors again. And on your side note, why shouldnt the ```__get__``` modify the ```self``` if I may ask?

Comment: It's like I said: if `__get__` modifies `self`, then the function called as a class method behaves like a bound method.