# How to pass callbacks and their arguments from wrapped function to decorator with Python 3.x?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am writing a generic wrapper around a REST API. I have several functions like the one below, responsible for retrieving a user from its email address. The part of interest is how the response is processed, based on a list of expected status codes (besides HTTP `200`) and callbacks associated to each expected status code:

```
import requests

def get_user_from_email(email):
    response = requests.get('http://example.com/api/v1/users/email:%s' % email)

    # define callbacks
    def return_as_json(response):
        print('Found user with email [%s].' % email)
        return response.json()

    def user_with_email_does_not_exist(response):
        print('Could not find any user with email [%s]. Returning `None`.' % email),
        return None

    expected_status_codes_and_callbacks = {
        requests.codes.ok: return_as_json,  # HTTP 200 == success
        404: user_with_email_does_not_exist,
    }
    if response.status_code in expected_status_codes_and_callbacks:
        callback = expected_status_codes_and_callbacks[response.status_code]
        return callback(response)
    else:
        response.raise_for_status()


john_doe = get_user_from_email('john.doe@company.com')
print(john_doe is not None)  # True

unregistered_user = get_user_from_email('unregistered.user@company.com')
print(unregistered_user is None)  # True
```

The code above works well so I want to refactor and generalize the response processing part. I would love to end up with the following code:

```
@process_response({requests.codes.ok: return_as_json, 404: user_with_email_does_not_exist})
def get_user_from_email(email):
    # define callbacks
    def return_as_json(response):
        print('Found user with email [%s].' % email)
        return response.json()

    def user_with_email_does_not_exist(response):
        print('Could not find any user with email [%s]. Returning `None`.' % email),
        return None

    return requests.get('https://example.com/api/v1/users/email:%s' % email)
```

with the `process_response` decorator defined as:

```
import functools

def process_response(extra_response_codes_and_callbacks=None):

    def actual_decorator(f):

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            response = f(*args, **kwargs)

            if response.status_code in expected_status_codes_and_callbacks:
                action_to_perform = expected_status_codes_and_callbacks[response.status_code]
                return action_to_perform(response)
            else:
                response.raise_for_status()  # raise exception on unexpected status code

        return wrapper

    return actual_decorator
```

My problem is the decorator complains about not having access to `return_as_json` and `user_with_email_does_not_exist` because these callbacks are defined *inside* the wrapped function.

If I decide to move the callbacks outside of the wrapped function, for example at the same level as the decorator itself, then the callbacks have no access to the response and email variables inside the wrapped function.

```
# does not work either, as response and email are not visible from the callbacks
def return_as_json(response):
    print('Found user with email [%s].' % email)
    return response.json()

def user_with_email_does_not_exist(response):
    print('Could not find any user with email [%s]. Returning `None`.' % email),
    return None

@process_response({requests.codes.ok: return_as_json, 404: user_with_email_does_not_exist})
def get_user_from_email(email):
    return requests.get('https://example.com/api/v1/users/email:%s' % email)
```

What is the right approach here? I find the decorator syntax very clean but I cannot figure out how to pass the required parts to it (either the callbacks themselves or their input arguments like `response` and `email`).

Comment: You could pass the `*args, **kwargs` into the `action_to_perform`.

Comment: If you assume that your reponse handlers, nested within the request function, are non-trivial, i.e. more than a few lines, you'd see that your intended "router" dispatching to either success or fail handlers really doesnt add up to much compared to your nested non-reusable handlers.   I'd write more code first before refactoring on this basis.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, see my comment below in reply to schwobaseggl

Comment: @JLPeyret I have indeed written a lot more code. All the API endpoints are covered, resulting in 25+ wrapper functions with the exact same architecture and response processing. Hence my desire to refactor all this with decorators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses function member data on class methods in order to map the response function to the appropriate callback. This seems like the cleanest syntax to me, but still has a class turning into a function (which could be easily avoided if desired).

```
# dummy response object
from collections import namedtuple
Response = namedtuple('Response', 'data status_code error')


def callback(status_code):
    def method(f):
        f.status_code = status_code
        return staticmethod(f)
    return method


def request(f):
    f.request = True
    return staticmethod(f)


def callback_redirect(cls):
    __callback_map = {}
    for attribute_name in dir(cls):
        attribute = getattr(cls, attribute_name)

        status_code = getattr(attribute, 'status_code', '')
        if status_code:
            __callback_map[status_code] = attribute

        if getattr(attribute, 'request', False):
            __request = attribute

    def call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        response = __request(*args, **kwargs)
        callback = __callback_map.get(response.status_code)
        if callback is not None:
            return callback(response)
        else:
            return response.error

    return call_wrapper


@callback_redirect
class get_user_from_email:

    @callback('200')
    def json(response):
        return 'json response: {}'.format(response.data)

    @callback('404')
    def does_not_exist(response):
        return 'does not exist'

    @request
    def request(email):
        response = Response(email, '200', 'exception')
        return response


print get_user_from_email('generic@email.com')
# json response: generic@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* convert the decorator keys into strings, and then pull the inner functions from the outer function passed to the decorator via `f.func_code.co_consts`. Don't do it this way.

```
import functools, new
from types import CodeType

def decorator(callback_dict=None):

    def actual_decorator(f):
        code_dict = {c.co_name: c for c in f.func_code.co_consts if type(c) is CodeType}

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            main_return = f(*args, **kwargs)

            if main_return['callback'] in callback_dict:
                callback_string = callback_dict[main_return['callback']]
                callback = new.function(code_dict[callback_string], {})
                return callback(main_return)

        return wrapper

    return actual_decorator


@decorator({'key_a': 'function_a'})
def main_function(callback):

    def function_a(callback_object):
        for k, v in callback_object.items():
            if k != 'callback':
                print '{}: {}'.format(k, v)

    return {'callback': callback, 'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2'}


main_function('key_a')
# key_1: value_1
# key_2: value_2
```

Can you use classes? The solution is immediate if you can use a class.

Comment: You mean using classes for the decorator part? Yes I can use classes, no problem. I have not investigated this path because I thought the features offered by both approaches were identical (classes vs. standard functions).

Comment: From what I understand, classes will help store a state. Is it what you have in mind? Then maybe the same result can be achieved with closures  and the `nonlocal` keyword in Python 3.x, as highlighted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650333/difference-between-decorator-classes-and-decorator-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If your main function is a class and your callbacks are methods, then calling those methods by string value is as simple as `getattr(cls, method_string)`. Again, you still will have to pass strings to the decorator, but you don't have to do the scary function inspection. I'll write up an example in a minute.

Comment: In this case, a class would be nice because it's an *object*, not because it preserves state.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments for my other answer, here is an answer that uses classes and decorators. It's a bit counter-intuitive because `get_user_from_email` is declared as a class, but ends up as a function after decorating. It does have the desired syntax however, so that's a plus. Maybe this could be a starting point for a cleaner solution.

```
# dummy response object
from collections import namedtuple
Response = namedtuple('Response', 'data status_code error')

def callback_mapper(callback_map):

    def actual_function(cls):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request = getattr(cls, 'request')
            response = request(*args, **kwargs)

            callback_name = callback_map.get(response.status_code)
            if callback_name is not None:
                callback_function = getattr(cls, callback_name)
                return callback_function(response)

            else:
                return response.error

        return wrapper

    return actual_function


@callback_mapper({'200': 'json', '404': 'does_not_exist'})
class get_user_from_email:

    @staticmethod
    def json(response):
        return 'json response: {}'.format(response.data)

    @staticmethod
    def does_not_exist(response):
        return 'does not exist'

    @staticmethod
    def request(email):
        response = Response('response data', '200', 'exception')
        return response

print get_user_from_email('blah')
# json response: response data
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared Goguen. It is not as immediate as I thought but I like it anyway. Sounds like a good start indeed.

Comment: @LaurentVaylet I'd check out the last solution with the `@callback` decorator. That seems like the most elegant structure to me.

Comment: You're right. The decorator is more convoluted but the end result might be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the function parameters of the outer function to the handlers:

```
def return_as_json(response, email=None):  # email param
    print('Found user with email [%s].' % email)
    return response.json()

@process_response({requests.codes.ok: return_as_json, 404: ...})
def get_user_from_email(email):
    return requests.get('...: %s' % email)

# in decorator
     # email param will be passed to return_as_json
     return action_to_perform(response, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I went this way at one point, but did not find the syntax very graceful. Here is what I had come up with in order to make the callback signature as generic as possible. `email` is not the only possible argument.

    def return_as_json(response, *args, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs.get('email') or args[1]  # assuming I know the index of the email argument in the original call
        print('Found user with email [%s].' % email)
        return response.json()