# What is the most Pythonic way to pass objects between imported libraries of code?

Tags: python

I have a program which imports two modules, one we will call `operations` (which is just a series of functions) and the other we call `tracking` (which is a class).  The program `tracking` module monitors a series of messages, has some error state flags, and so forth.  The program sorts information in `tracking` by severity and relevant parties, then dumps this to different files at the end.

I create a single instance of the tracking class with `myTrack = tracking.Tracking()`.  (Yes, this is [global state and therefore bad](/questions/2774468/please-describe-your-struggles-with-minimizing-use-of-global-variables), but it is pretty handy)

Unforunately, I would like to use my `tracking` object within the `operations` module, just to track errors and warnings.  It looks like I can pass `myTrack` to functions in the `operations` module as an argument, modifying each and every one of the functions.

However, is there a "better" or "more Pythonic" way to do this?  I suspect there is something with namespaces which I have failed to grasp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could refactor this, but one place you might start is to add a `track()` function to your `operations` module. Have it do nothing by default.

```
 def track(message):  # use the right signature though!
     pass
```

In your `operations` module you would then call your `track()` function anywhere you might want to track something.

Assuming your `Tracking` object has a method called `track()` that does the actual tracking, then in your main module, you can do this:

```
myTrack = tracking.Tracking()
operations.track = myTrack.track
```

This replaces the module's (do-nothing) `track` function with the method from your `Tracking` instance.

Basically, you have provided a "hook" which anyone can use to add tracking to your `operations` module, and then used that hook yourself.

Yes, this is more "global state," but it's module-global, which is not really global.

Comment: Ah, and I could then use *args in for the message in case I ever change the arguments in the tracking module!

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use `*args`, as listing the actual arguments to a function is good documentation. If you change the signature of your `tracking` module, you will have to change every call to `track()` in your `operations` module anyway, so you'll be in there and can just update your dummy function's signature then.

Comment: Also, if you want to be *really* fancy and allow any number of other functions to attach to this "hook" you could use what I came up with for a similar question I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309607/whats-the-preferred-way-to-implement-a-hook-or-callback-in-python/4321509#4321509

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand your problem correctly, but I think you are looking for a way to make the functions in one module automatically aware of the state an object in another module without explicitly passing that object every time you call a function.

The basic problem is that at some level you have to pass the object and have it available to all the functions you need. Modules are simply not meant to work like that.

I think a better idea will be to define an `Operations` class that contains all the functions you need as methods as well as holding an instance of `Tracking`. You can just pass in your `Tracking` object and create an `Operations` instance, and use that to call whatever function that you need.

```
myTrack = tracking.Tracking()
myOperation=operations.Operations(myTrack)
myOperation.doSomething()
```

Comment: This is also a good solution that is only a smidge less preferable to me than the kindall's.

Comment: Our two solutions are actually pretty much the same, it's just that I'm using the module as the namespace (since it is already a singleton object) and MAK's suggesting using a class for the purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass `myTrack` to the `Operations()` constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Your `tracking` module (recording details about a series of events for later analysis or display) sounds suspiciously like the standard library's `logging` module. So you may want to investigate that a little more closely.

If you decide to head down that path, then the `operations` module would just log events to a specific logger (e.g. "myapp.operations"), your `tracking` module would provide a logging handler that did what you wanted, and your main module would hook the two together (by registering the tracking handler with the "myapp.operations" logger).

You can also set up something like that yourself, but really, if you want to track events in a Python program... just use `logging`.